# Subscribe doesn't have a response

Tags: javascript, angular

```
goBack() {

    this.generateCode()


    this.offerService.removeAllSelectedProducts(this.offer.products)
      .pipe(filter((removedProducts) => removedProducts))
      .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(["/home"]))
  }

  generateCode() {

    let offerCode
    if (navigator.onLine) {
      this.customerId = localStorage.getItem(LocalstorageKeyEnum.SELECTED_CUSTOMER)
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LocalstorageKeyEnum.SELECTED_CUSTOMER)).id
        : "NEW";

      if (this.customerId === "NEW") {
        this.countNewOffers = 1;
      }
      else {
        this.loading = true;
        let offersByIdObservable = this.offerService.getOpportunityCount(this.customerId)
        offersByIdObservable.pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
          .subscribe(
            (data) => {
              this.loading = false;
              this.countNewOffers = data + 1;
            },
            (error) => {
              if (error.status === 404) {
                this.loading = false;
                this.countNewOffers = 1;
              }
            }
          );
      }
      offerCode = "OF-" + this.customerId + "-" + (this.countNewOffers ? this.countNewOffers : "NEW");
      this.offer.code = offerCode;

      localStorage.setItem(LocalstorageKeyEnum.OFFER, JSON.stringify(this.offer));
    } else {
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
}
```

I have this two functions, when I click on a button I call the function goBack() that launches the generateCode()

This function (generateCode()) makes the request (the status code is 200). I have tried to debug and it doesn't enter subscribe data or error, so this.countNewOffers results undefined.

I don't understand why it doesn't enter in data or error, but the api call is a 200 with blank response. (but if I call from another place, like swagger, it works and give me back a number)

Comment: provide working example so we can try to bedbug it.

Comment: your network tab in devtool show some response for the api?

Comment: @AmitKumar it's strange, because it results 200 but the response is blank and not with a number

Comment: My api call is an Observable, maybe it goes forward and I lost the async

Comment: Try the same api in postman with same coustomer id.